# "Unable to parse relevantDate " error while parsing pkpass in ios

Tags: iphone

Not able to create pass

```
Error Domain=PKPassKitErrorDomain Code=1 "The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid."
UserInfo=0x1405a480 {NSUnderlyingError=0x14059950 "Unable to parse relevantDate 2013-12-05T06:00:00.000Z as a date. 
We expect dates in "W3C date time stamp format", either "Complete date plus hours and minutes" or 
"Complete date plus hours, minutes and seconds". For example, 1980-05-07T10:30-05:00.", NSLocalizedDescription=The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.}
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, this is not a **[real question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145677/what-is-a-real-question)** for here. Can you a self contained snip of the code you used to produce this error? Did you try anything so far? Please show your efforts first so that other people might help you out. Also, please read **[FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help)** and **[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: The error message gives you a lot of detail and suggested fixes. If those are not helpful, you need to provide more detail about what exactly you are doing when this occurs.

Answer (score 0):

The format is valid. Sounds like a bug in Passbook. It's not able to parse UTC timezone.